# React Native, NavigationExperimental Animations

Tags: navigation, react-native

Does React Native Navigation experimental support slide from bottom, slide from left, fade effects etc? If yes how do we do it. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render your scene using `renderScene` of `NavigationTransitioner`, you get `props` object that contains `layout`, `position`, `scene` and `progress`. You can use them with your custom interpolation function to create any animation you like.

At this time, react native seems to have only `right-to-left` and `bottom-to-up` animations out-of-the-box. You can use them via `NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator`: `forHorizontal` and `forVertical`.

See: [NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/ac5636dd59f97a7381acd548e701e83fadcba408/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.js) for more details.

If your code looks like: [RN-NavigationExperimental-Redux-Example](https://github.com/jlyman/RN-NavigationExperimental-Redux-Example/blob/master/app/containers/AppContainer.js#L42-L50)

You can define `style` property of `NavigationCard` like:

```
<NavigationCard
  {...props}
  style={NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical(props)}
  renderScene={this._renderScene}
  key={props.scene.navigationState.key}
/>
```

This will change transition from left-to-right to bottom-to-up.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to note `cardStyleInterpolator` property [was added](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/c8a7f9e2d1618b5feea68915b5e2e4f12247ceed) to `NavigationCardStack`. So soon (with RN 0.41 and above) it will be possible to use custom animations without rewriting card stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you need left-to-right to top-to-bottom animations you write your own custom interpolator. You could use the NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator component as a template and make the changes needed. E.g. see the following link to implement top-to-buttom animations:

[React Navtive NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical() - How can I change the direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476605/react-navtive-navigationcardstackstyleinterpolator-forvertical-how-can-i-cha/39476796#39476796)