# React Native NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical() - How can I change the direction?

Tags: react-native

I want the card to appear from the top instead of from the bottom. Is there a way to do this when using `NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical()`?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to use my own custom interpolator.

We could use the [NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/fc864a22bd00464c4219c6ddb6aa3d923aeb26dc/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.js) component as a template and change

```
  const translateY = position.interpolate({
inputRange,
outputRange: ([height, 0, -10]: Array<number>)});
```

to

```
  const translateY = position.interpolate({
inputRange,
outputRange: ([-height, 0, -10]: Array<number>)});
```