# react native: How to listen to component position?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I tried to play with different kind of position callbacks but nothing fit my needs.

- onLayout doesn't update
- measure() with setInterval is too heavy
- onPanResponderMove blocks child gestures

I want to retrieve Scene component position during navigator transition.

To be more precise, here's a sample : https://rnplay.org/apps/53SXZg. How to retrieve dragged scene position?

Comment: If you're using `Animated`, can't you add an event listener to the value as it changes? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#addlistener

Comment: Thanks, I use classic Navigator.SceneConfigs and a custom gesture to drag/swipe scenes. I need to retrieve the scene position on the drag. The only way i found is to measure() it and callback on the parent component. With a setInterval and its too much consuming and dirty. I don't know how i could add a listener (with Animated but where?). This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350129/react-native-navigationexperimental-animations) talks about a progress prop on NavigatorExperimental but I'm slow to understand it and not really sure it will callback position...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it using `NavigationTransitionner` of `NavigatorExperimental`. Thanks jered. Listening to transitionProps.position AnimatedValue :

```
_render(transitionProps: NavigationTransitionProps,): React.Element<any> {
  const scenes = transitionProps.scenes.map((scene) => {
    const sceneProps = {
      ...transitionProps,
      scene,
    };
    return this._renderScene(sceneProps);
  });

  // Add position listener
  if(!this.positionListener){
    this.positionListener = transitionProps.position.addListener(({value}) => {
    console.log('value', value);
    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.navigator}>
      {scenes}
    </View>
  );
}
```