# React Native listen position of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to listen the position of a view I am moving with a pan responder.
I am using the onLayout prop to get the width, height, x and y positions, but it only runs when the first render. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see this post, maybe it help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529757/12282249

Comment: not working for me :(