# React Native how to listen to element position changing and get its xy?

Tags: react-native

How can i listen in React Native / Expo when element moves and get all its coordinates?

I tried looking into this one [react native: How to listen to component position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511097/react-native-how-to-listen-to-component-position/40529757#40529757) but this is old tread i can't seem to find or use those suggestion in modern RN

Comment: I have a View block, when keyboard pop up it moved it higher, this is ok, but i have a case that i need to get those coordinates. so if it moves by 50 higher i want to catch all each pixel of that event

Comment: lets with Gesture from `ReAnimated` library, save initiate position in `onStart`, listen to position change in `onUpdate`